# usort() not processing correctly

Tags: php, json

My array from a json result is returned as follows :

```
["AuctionInfo"]=>
[0]=>
array(13) {
  ["price"]=>  
    int(3000)
} 
[1]=>
array(13) {
  ["price"]=>
     int(5000)
```

My PHP code i was attempting to use was simply

```
<?php
$decoded = json_decode("my json api", true);
foreach($decoded['AuctionInfo'] as $item) { 
usort($decoded['AuctionInfo']['price']);?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I tried adding `usort($decoded['AuctionInfo']['price']` after my `foreach` but that just throws errors, would anyone be able to point me in the correct direction please ?

All i want to do is sort the `$decoded['AuctionInfo']['price']` in descending order

Comment: pls show your usort() part of code..and errors too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'AuctionInfo' => array(
        array('price' => 500),
        array('price' => 3000)
    )
);

$decoded = $data['AuctionInfo'];
foreach($decoded as $item) {
    echo $item['price'] . PHP_EOL;
}

usort($decoded, function($a, $b) { return $a['price'] < $b['price'] ? 1 : -1; });

foreach($decoded as $item) {
    echo $item['price'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: you're amazing that worked although it's throwing `Warning: usort() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in` but the actual sorting is working

Comment: I don't get this error when I execute the code I posted.  Can you post the code you're running that is giving you this error?

Comment: Sorry, my error i left my old code in the file too, thanks for this !

Comment: My pleasure.  Always glad to be of assistance.

Comment: this code is actually not complete, the equality case is missing in the comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

There is another level of index in your code that you forgot.
for example this would be valid

```
<?php echo $decoded['AuctionInfo'][1]['price'] ?>
>5000
```

however how you are currently have is `$decoded['AuctionInfo']['price']` which does not result in an array, it searches for the index `price` within your index of integers.

There are a few ways to get around this, the simplest would be to create your own compare function that checks the `price` in the compared elements:

```
function price_cmp($a, $b){
    if ($a["price"] == $b["price"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ($a["price"] < $b["price"]){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}
usort($decoded, "price_cmp");
```